# Setting the width and height of an <object/> using material design light

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed a flash game in a webpage using [material design lite](https://www.getmdl.io/). I declare the object in this context:

```
<body class="mdl-demo mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-700 mdl-base">
    <div style="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
       ...
       <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash " style="width:1024px;height:576px">
       ...
       </object>
   </div>
</body>
```

Looking into chrome developer tools, I can see that "width" and "height" of the object are set to "auto".

[image]

How can I set them to my desired values?

Comment: See its not a problem , it applied height as 576 px only

Comment: Are you telling me that the debug output of chrome means, that "height" is set tot "576px"? Because the visual size of the object on screen is not 576px.

Comment: But why does it say "auto" next to height? And why is the object not 576px height?